# Delete old records from DataSet and reload view c#

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset

In ADO.NET I have class with my DataSet object. In Window Form aplication I have 3 linked listBoxes. 1. displays a nr, 2. "name" value from table and 3. "description" from table. When I add a new row to dataSet I can delete it, but problem is when im trying to delete a rows that were in dataSet from the beggining. 
Deleting:

```
int licznik = 0;
foreach(DataRow datarow in bez.dset.Tables["typ"].Rows)
{
    if(datarow["nazwa"].ToString() == listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString())
    {
        break;
    }
    licznik++;
}

bez.dset.Tables["typ"].Rows[licznik].Delete();
```

baz is a class with DataSet object.
When I refresh a listBoxes there is an an error that its imposible to get acces to the information that have been deleted. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Delete method doesn't remove the row from the DataSet table. It just marks the DataRow.[RowState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate(v=vs.110).aspx) with the enum [DataRowState.Deleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate(v=vs.110).aspx). And if you try to reference a DataRow with its RowState = DataRowState.Deleted the mentioned error is raised.

This approach is required if you want to persist your changes back to the database. If you think about it, how do you manage to delete the row from the database table if the row deleted is no more in the DataSet table?

If you want to remove the row deleted from the in-memory datatable then you need to call

```
bez.dset.Tables["typ"].AcceptChanges();
```

This calls applies your changes to the in memory DataTable changing every row RowState to DataRowState.Unchanged and removing the deleted rows. Of course, after this call the ADO.NET classes like the DbDataAdapter are no more able to persist your changes back to the database.

If you keep your DataRow with the RowState set to DataRowState.Deleted in your Datatable then you need to check for every RowState before trying to use it

```
foreach (DataRow drow in bez.dset.Tables["typ"].Rows) 
{
   if(drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
   {
       string value = drow.Field<string>("NameOfYourColumnOfStringType");
       ..... whatever you want to do with it....
   }
}
```

Comment: So should I check before displaying every row if it is "marked" as deleted by bez.dset.Tables["typ"].Rows[licznik].Delete(); and if its not then display it?